# How to create a button from an anchor link and align it?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a specific header, and I need to make a button out of an anchor link. I was able to do so with some styling but I'm having trouble aligning it in the upper right corner.

HTML:

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="https://imgur.com/bz1TMTx.png">
    <a class="logout-button" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
  <div class="header-content">
    <h1 class="header-title">Dessert Island</h1>
    <h4 class="header-greet">Welcome user!</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #FFF5FF;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.header-title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.header-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 30px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header-greet {
  width: 100%;
}

.logout-button {
  display: block;
  width: 115px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #3A10E5;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

I'm trying to create the following image:

[image: header]

I have the following jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0sjhn971/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by making your element's position absolute. I added the solution in your code:

```
.logout-button {
  position: absolute; /* Add This*/
  top: 30px; /* Add This*/
  right: 30px; /* Add This*/
  display: block;
  width: 115px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #3A10E5;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mdn says about `position: absolute` property:

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is
> created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative
> to its **closest positioned ancestor**, if any; otherwise, it is placed
> relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is
> determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.

So try to use `position: absolute`:

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #FFF5FF;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.header-title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.header-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 30px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header-greet {
  width: 100%;
}

.logout-button {
  display: block;
  width: 115px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #3A10E5;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <img src="https://imgur.com/bz1TMTx.png">
    <a class="logout-button" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
    <div class="header-content">
      <h1 class="header-title">Dessert Island</h1>
      <h4 class="header-greet">Welcome user!</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add those css for your .logout-button class

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
```

It will change the position to the right top. Now control the button with top and right value.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the logout-button after the header-content and give it a `margin-left: auto;`

**Working example:**

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #FFF5FF;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 25px;         /* added padding because it's shown in your image */
}

.header-title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.header-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 30px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header-greet {
  width: 100%;
}

.logout-button {
  display: inline;
  width: 115px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #3A10E5;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="https://imgur.com/bz1TMTx.png">
  <div class="header-content">
    <h1 class="header-title">Dessert Island</h1>
    <h4 class="header-greet">Welcome user!</h4>
  </div>
  <a class="logout-button" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
</div>
```